# make my gtk buttons more windows-like

Tags: windows, windows-7, gtk, pygtk

How can I get my gtk buttons to look more like standard windows buttons? In this particular example, I have OK and Cancel buttons, but they're a different size than the OK and Cancel buttons in every windows app. How can I change their size to look more like windows'?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't immediately see any ways to do it programmatically, but it appears that you can set per-application GTK themes according to [this page](http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/setting-a-custom-gtk-theme-for-specific-applications/).  There are GTK themes that appear more Windows-like, I believe.